# WIX: How to display "Publisher" info in "Programs and Features" -> "Installed Updates"

Tags: wix, msi-patch

I am responsible for creating several MSI's and their MSP's. I installed all of them using the MSI's, and my company name was displayed correctly, i.e. under "Programs and Features". However, after I installed their updates using the MSP's, I found their "Publisher" columns in "Programs and Features" -> "Installed Updates" were blank for some of the products, while some of them had my company name.

I am so surprised after seeing those blank publishers because I always use the following Patch.wxs as a template and add componentRef's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?include ..\PatchVersion.wxi ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Patch AllowRemoval="yes"
        Manufacturer="MyCompany" 
        MoreInfoURL="http://www.mycompany.com/"
        DisplayName="My Studio Patch1" 
        Description="My Studio Patch1" 
        Classification="Update Rollup"
        >

        <Media Id="5000" Cabinet="RTM.cab">
            <PatchBaseline Id="RTM" ><Validate ProductId='no' ProductVersionOperator='LesserOrEqual'/></PatchBaseline>
        </Media>

        <PatchFamilyRef Id="MyStudio_1_Rollup"/>
    </Patch>

    <Fragment>  
        <PatchFamily Id='MytStudio_1_Rollup' Version='$(env.PATCH_VERSION)' Supersede='yes'>
            <ComponentRef Id="..." />
        </PatchFamily>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I thought Patch/@Manufacturer is the one for the publisher column. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Later I found that this only occurs in x64 OS env. For x64 MSI's, I see "Publisher" info in "Installed Updates", and for x32 MSI's, I see blank "Publisher". I thought it might be Wix version, so I upgraded it from v3.7 to v3.9, but it didn't help.